How can I pass String as an argument in Dart?
Issue arises at line  Text(textToDisplay)
I get the error Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
class IconText extends StatelessWidget {
  const IconText({super.key, required this.icon, required this.textToDisplay});

  final IconData icon;
  final String textToDisplay;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.male,
          size: 80,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 15),
        Text(textToDisplay)
      ],
    );
  }
}

I consume this widget like so
const Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: [
              NewWidget(
                color: widgetColor,
                cardChild: IconText(icon: Icons.male, textToDisplay: "Male"),
              ),
              NewWidget(
                color: widgetColor,
                cardChild: IconText(icon: Icons.male, textToDisplay: "Female"),
              )
            ],
          )),

How can I fix this error?

Remove the const keyword before Column in the build method of IconText widget.

You cannot pass textToDisplay as a compile-time constant because it might not be one.  Since it might not be a compile-time constant, the Text widget (and its containing Column widget) cannot be compile-time constants either, so you should remove the const keyword.

You have to remove the const of your column
class IconText extends StatelessWidget {
  const IconText({super.key, required this.icon, required this.textToDisplay});

  final IconData icon;
  final String textToDisplay;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Icon(
          Icons.male,
          size: 80,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 15),
        Text(textToDisplay)
      ],
    );
  }
}

